# What should I change in the app.json file to rebuild my app from expo?

Tags: ios, build, version, expo, rebuild

I am planning to rebuild my app. 

What settings should be changed to change from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0?

I wonder about the rebuilding procedure and the setting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUeBM.jpg)

Can I do this?

step1) change app.json

step2) $ expo build:ios

```
{
  "expo": {
     "name": "my app",
     "version": "1.1.0",    <=== Change this code?
     "ios": {
       "buildNumber": "1.1.0",    <=== Change this code?
       ...
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

"version": "1.1.0"

because the buildNumber means the number of file of your version, you can create a lot buildNumber for a one version.